# MongoDB Aggregation using NativeQuery

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, nativequery

I'm trying to do a simple aggregation in mongoDB using NativeQuery. Is it possible? I made many tests but I can't find a solution.
The query is :

```
 String query = "{ $match : 
                        { dateTimestamp : 
                              { $gt : 1452380400000 , $lt :1453222518000}}
                        } ,
                    { $group : 
                    { _id : {hour:
                                { $hour : '$date'}
                             } ,
                            'myData' : { $push : '$dataUsed'}
                      }
                    },
                    { $sort : { 'dataUsed' : -1}}";


    Object resultObject = em.createNativeQuery(query,MyClass.class).getSingleResult();
```

> The error is : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level
>   operator: $match"

MongoDB version3.0

hibernate-ogm-mongodb 4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try an "invocation" of MongoDB's **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** API:

```
String nativeQuery = "db.collection.aggregate(["
    + "{ $match: { dateTimestamp: { $gt: 1452380400000, $lt: 1453222518000 } } }," // WHERE
    + "{ $group: { _id: { hour: { $hour : '$date'} }, myData: { $push: '$dataUsed' } } }," // GROUP BY
    + "{ $sort : { '_id.hour': -1 } }]"; // ORDER BY

Query query = em.createNativeQuery(nativeQuery, MyClass.class);
```

Comment: not work for me: when i try to do query.getSingleResult()... I have a JsonParse exception ....